# flushing events to X11

Tags: c, linux, xlib

I'm creating an xlib application that sends an alt tab to X11
I want those events flushed as quickly as possible to send the next combination of keys:

```
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 64, True, 0);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 23, True, 0);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 23, False, 0);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 64, False, 0);
XFlush(dis);
sleep(1);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 65, True, 0);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 65, False, 0);
XFlush(dis);
```

I want the first set of keypresses to work BEFORE the second set, unfortunately this does not happen unless I let the application sleep for 1 second between both flushes
I've tried xsync as well but no dice

thanks

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do that reliably. With "I want the ... keypresses to work" you probably mean to wait for the application that finally handle the keypresses to do and finish their thing. But those actions are not done by the X server, but by another client application. And that client applications do not usually notify the X server when they finish doing whatever they do... in response to events...

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [manual page](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XSync.3.html), compare with `XSync`:

> The `XFlush` function flushes the output buffer. Most client applications need not use this function because the output buffer is automatically flushed as needed by calls to `XPending`, `XNextEvent`, and `XWindowEvent`. Events generated by the server may be enqueued into the library's event queue.

while

> The `XSync` function flushes the output buffer *and then **waits** until all requests have been received and processed by the X server*. Any errors generated must be handled by the error handler. For each protocol error received by Xlib, `XSync` calls the client application's error handling routine (see section 11.8.2). Any events generated by the server are enqueued into the library's event queue.

Your application needs to **wait** (and the sleep is redundant).  Use `XSync`.

Comment: by wait do you mean use the wait function or literally wait?
in both cases how do I do that
xsync is not working without the sleep function

Comment: `XSync` waits.  As for "not working", a complete program helps with discussion.

Comment: you want me to post the complete program?

Comment: If it's short, it is helpful (bear in mind that time is always limited).

Comment: `code`
void func(void)
{
Display *dis;
dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
char hello[]="hello world";
//switch to active window: alt+tab
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 64, True, 0);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 23, True, 0);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 23, False, 0);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 64, False, 0);
//XFlush(dis);
XSync(dis,False);
//sleep(1);
int size=sizeof(hello);
int i;
char temp;
for (i=0;i<size;i++)
{
hello[i];
switch (hello[i])
{
case ' ':
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 65, True, 0);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(dis, 65, False, 0);
break;
//the rest is a huge character comparison table
XSync(dis,False);
XCloseDisplay(dis);
}

Comment: see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think this is as short as I can get the code(while retaining its relativity to the problem)
is the code not clear though?